# watson vision API response FAIL - but reason?

Tags: ibm-watson

I get the following response from the Watson Vision API Explorer, after it churns on my request for about 20 minutes:

```
{
  "X-Backside-Transport": "FAIL FAIL",
  "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate",
  "Date": "Fri, 29 Jul 2016 07:39:58 GMT",
  "Server": "nginx",
  "x-powered-by": "Express",
  "x-request-id": "g7bi4ql7pjiiukt62slb19a5oua4lumh",
  "X-Vcap-Request-Id": "b53d9197-4d7f-45f5-57c9-7dadf08e60f5",
  "x-client-ip": "195.176.20.45",
  "X-Global-Transaction-ID": "2915345487"
}
```

I figure that the request to train a new classifier has Failed ("FAIL FAIL") but can anyone decypher this message as to WHY it has failed?

Any quilified insight are highly welcome !

Comment: what was your request? what was the HTTP response you got? read https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/#error-handling for a list of the error codes.

Answer (score 0):

This is ALL I got, and finally figured that "backside-transport" failed, possibly because the amount of training image data was too large... it is said is has to be < 100MB, I only succeeded when it was < 20MB.  Oh well, just a metter of imprecise documentation - and no, there was NO error-code given.